# Copy, rename and move all files in directory

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I have many pdf files I need to Copy, Rename and Move.
Copy and move works – I just can’t figure out how the rename part it’s done.

The files look like this:

```
2021-05-05_10-10-12-609_Testperson_Nancy_2512489996_19490816_OD_20210429112706.pdf  
2021-06-05_11-11-12-135_Testperson_with_many _Names_0708681234_19490817_OD_20210429112715.pdf
```

and I need them to be renamed to:

```
251248-9996_19490816_OD_20210429112706.pdf  
070868-1234_19490817_OD_20210429112715.pdf
```

So need to substring from the fourth `_` from the right (without the first `_`) with a `-` between [6] and [7].

This is what I got so far:

```
SET input=c:\temp\rename\input
SET backup=c:\temp\rename\backup
SET output=c:\temp\rename\output

if not exist "%backup%" mkdir "%backup%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%input%\*.pdf"') DO (
xcopy /-y "%%F" "%backup%" & move "%%F" "%output%"
)
```

`c:\temp\rename\input` *(for original files)*
`c:\temp\rename\backup` *(backup dir for orginal files)*
`c:\temp\rename\output` *(renamed files)*

This must be run as a scheduled batch file job on Windows Server (I know how to run the job)

Comment: is the format always exactly like this? `2021-05-05_10-10-12-609_Testperson_Nancy_2512489996_19490816_OD_20210429112706.pdf`

Comment: Yes – but the only thing that is fixed is the last four “_”.
_0708681234_19490817_OD_20210429112715.pdf
_0708684123_145521747587_OD_20210429112715.pdf

Comment: ok, you'll need to provide some real scenarios, this is throwing of the standard. `2021-06-05_11-11-12-135_Testperson_with_many _Names_0708681234_19490817_OD_20210429112715.pdf ` So please provide examples as they actaully are, you can change names if need be, but the format is critical here.

Comment: The first part of the file can vary in numbers of words according to the person’s name.
The four last underscores will always be there but the numbers / text in-between can vary in length except for the first (e.g. Mr. Croft 0708681234) that number will always be 10 characters long.  
2021-06-05_11-11-12-135_Jim_Johnson_Hansen _Croft_0708681234_19490817_OD_20210429112715.pdf  
2021-05-05_10-10-12-609_John_Doe_2512489996_194_ABC_20210529115705.pdf

Comment: so there are not a set number of `_`?

Comment: @Compo, Yes, I understand, but the questions were asked simply because I did not know how the last part of the string can differ. i.e an additional item separated by `_`

Comment: Exactly, @Compo but seemed that will not work based on the last comment by OP.

Comment: @JonasHansen, could you please clarify whether there would ever be a scenario where two or more concurrent underscores exist in that particular area, _(wanted part)_ of the filename?

Comment: @Compo Never always only one underscore

Comment: Removing information from the file names, is not reversible, therefore not a very good backup scheme.

Comment: @jwdonahue, You're right, that why the first step in the loop is to make a copy of the file to backup-dir with the original file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go. I would suggest you first make a backup of your files before running this in on your production files:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "input=c:\temp\rename\input"
set "backup=c:\temp\rename\backup"
set "output=c:\temp\rename\output"
mkdir "%backup%">nul 2>&1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%input%\*.pdf"') do (
    set "cnt=-4"
    set "_tmp=%%~i"
    set "_tmp=!_tmp: =-!
    set "_strip=!_tmp:_= !"
    for %%c in (!_strip!) do (
    set /a cnt+=1
 )
    if !cnt! gtr 1 if defined _tmp call :parser !cnt! "%%i"
)
goto :eof
:parser
for /f "tokens=%~1,* delims=_" %%a in ("%~2") do set "fin=%%~b"
echo xcopy /-y "%~2" "%backup%"
echo move "%~2" "%output%\%fin:~0,6%-%fin:~6%"
```

Some things to note. This does **not** yet do the actual `copy` or `move`, it will just `echo` the results, as a safety measure. So once you see it does what it should, then you can remove `echo` from the last two lines.

Lastly this is assuming the file format as you gave it, but it does cater for whitespace as well as double `_` but it will go south if you have another `_` separated section which does not form part of the standard format.

**Demo**
Given the 4 examples you gave in your question and comment (with the exception of the `C:\tmp\Input` in my example as I use a different directory to test):
[image]

Comment: Looks like it’s working, unfortunately, it's late in Denmark so I will continue testing in the morning. Thanx for helping out – will keep you updated on how it works.

Comment: I've amended the code to include your current code, you should be able to run it as is, obviously by removing the `echo`s on the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this easier using PowerShell, but to remain on topic, here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which gets some assistance from [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "input=C:\temp\rename\input"
Set "backup=C:\temp\rename\backup"
Set "output=C:\temp\rename\output"
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=|" %%G In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile
     "Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '%input%' -Filter '*_*_*_*_*.pdf' -File | "
     "ForEach-Object { $_.FullName + '|' + "
     "(($_.Name).Split('_')[-4]).Insert(6,'-') + '_' + "
     "(($_.Name).Split('_')[-3..-1] -Join('_')) }"') Do (
    Echo=%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%G" "%backup%\" && (
        Echo=Move /Y "%%G" "%output%\%%H"))
Pause
```

Currently the script will just show you the commands it will run, if you're happy with the output, then delete `Echo=` from lines `12` and `13` and optionally the last line. As a side note, I used a trailing backward slash for the [xcopy](/questions/tagged/xcopy) destination, this will cause `%backup%` to be created, if it does not already exist.